# Where does HTK save the outputs?

Tags: output, speech-recognition

Im working on a project using HTK speech recognision toolkit, and I have finished the recogniser properly. But now, I want to do different aplications with the different recognised words, so I need to know where does HTK save the recognised words, because I need to make an aplication who is going to work live. If someone knows about HTK and its outputs please answer me.

Thanks!

Pete.

Comment: Nobody answered so I think the message doesnt explain my question well. I will try to explain it again. I am making a project using HTK, I have already done my speech recognition system succesfuly, this system recognises some short sentences to move a hospital bed. Now I want to use the recognised sentences in another software to simulate a hospital bed, so I need to know how I can connect HTK live recogniser with the other software to make them work together, and for that I supose that I need to know where does HTK save all recognised sentences. If someone knows something about answer me.